# Unable to create a new project in Web2Project

Tags: open-source, project-management

I recently downloaded Web2Project after going through the reviews. Installation was a breeze and the application is neatly aligned. I was able to create the users, assign permissions, create companies etc.

However when I am trying to create a project , despite filling all the fields in the screen the page just refreshes back without giving any error message or creating a project.

I am looking to see if there is a way to troubleshoot what is going on with the page. I tried exploring to create an account in Web2Project support forums but not able to create an account through the available media and hence seeking technical assistance through Stackoverflow.

Web2Project New Installation

Web2Project Code (Just installed on WAMP Server) -- Projects Module

After filling all the fields in the Project Screen, the project should be created.

But the screen just refreshes without creating the project. No errors shown. When I go to Project List page nothing is created.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem. Took a lot of work until realized that the cause was the field PROJECT_ID of the table PROJECTS was not created with the auto increment definition. I just seted up this property and the problem was solved.

How did i discover the cause of the problem? In the SYSTEM ADMIN module, access the SYSTEM CONFIGURATION page, and then set the value of the field DEBUG LEVEL to 1, and check the field SHOW DEBUG MESSAGES. This will allow the web2project to log into C:\Windows\Temp\PHP72x64_errors.log (in case of my instalation) the error.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. Let me check this tonight and keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem and took a lot time to solved until I came here.

Goto the table project immediately, found no auto_increment in project_id field. Put it on, it worked!

And hoping current web2Project maintainer will fix this in their installer.

Thank you!